# Anonymous commenting in Socialengine

Tags: socialengine

How do I implement the ability of non members to leave comments on Socialengine articles, photos, etc? Any module doing this?

Comment: Technically, it is possible. But I don't think you'll find any plugin for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is start trying disqus system. But it needs some time to be adapted to socialengine. Contact me if you'll need some help.